# eq not getting correct, 2nd element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, selector

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
mycars = {};

function dodat(){
var btn=document.createElement("div");
btn.style.width="25px";
btn.style.height="25px";
btn.style.backgroundColor="red";
btn.style.boxShadow="inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
btn.style.position="absolute";
btn.style.left="0px";
var numba = Math.round(Math.random()*10000000000);
btn.id=numba;
mycars[numba] = -100;

var move = function(){
mycars[numba] = mycars[numba]+1;
document.getElementById(numba).style.left=mycars[numba]+"px";
};

setInterval(move, 10);

document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
}
</script>

<body>

<div style="background-color:#c3c3c3;width:500px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;" id="track"></div>
</body>

<script>
setInterval("dodat();", "1000");
</script>
<script>
setInterval('alert($("div:eq(1)").position().left);', '1000');
</script>
```

I have a problem, as the blobs keep scrolling the jQuery `div:eq(1)` does not get the second element, it seems to be getting the last element or something, its not dynamic.

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: You just made me cry! That is just sad.

Comment: Wait, you're being sarcastic? @adeneo

Comment: No, not really! You have a script tag before the doctype, lots of javascript  that could have been done so much simpler by using jQuery, as you're including it anyway, intervals that evals functions, and the issue is, once you pass something to an interval like that, it's not updated when you change a variable or update the DOM, so it won't update.

Answer (score 0):

Write code when DOM gets ready.

Try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        alert($("div:eq(0)").position().left);
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3MC4/1/)